# How do I move menu to the bottom in Custom Community theme?

Tags: theme-development, menus

I am new to Wordpress and created the following website:  www.sugarhausbyamy.com
I would like to move my menu to the bottom of the screen.  Is there an easy way to do this?  I would also like to change the font in the menu.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the main menu bar at the top-- the one with the grey background-- then look for `id="header"` in your theme files, maybe in `header.php` but I can't promise that. Then move that associated `div` to below your content. That will mean moving it to another file, maybe `footer.php` but again I can't promise you. Once you move it you may have (probably will have) formatting issues to sort out.